# AWS CLI: listener ARN "must be in ARN format" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli, amazon-elb

I'm using a local exec provisioner in terraform to run aws cli commands that get around terraform's lack of support for certain aws features. The command in question is to create a `listener-rule` for Application Load Balancer. Here's the call in question (numbers fuzzed):

```
aws elbv2 create-rule 
--listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-1:394416156998:listener/app/lb-name/22e3a19c3c684f8b/17032dfaae523461 
--priority 2 
--conditions Field=http-request-method,Values='GET' 
--actions Type=forward,TargetGroupArn=arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-1:394416159845:targetgroup/target-group-name/2ff8e99a44a24219
```

This yields the error:

```
(ValidationError) when calling the CreateRule operation: 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-1:394416155421:listener/app/alb-name/92e1a32c3c684f2b/64032dfaae753032' must be in ARN format
```

However, if you examine the [example in amazon's own documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/create-rule.html), they use exactly the same ARN format, unless I'm missing the obvious.

Here's my terraform code:

```
resource "null_resource" "rule-maker" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws elbv2 create-rule --listener-arn ${data.aws_arn.listener-arn.arn} --priority 2 --conditions Field=http-request-method,Values='GET' --actions Type=forward,TargetGroupArn=${aws_alb_target_group.name.arn}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try enclosing `${data.aws_arn.listener-arn.arn}` in double quotes like: `"aws elbv2 create-rule --listener-arn \"${data.aws_arn.listener-arn.arn}\" --priority 2 --conditions Field=http-request-method,Values='GET' --actions Type=forward,TargetGroupArn=${aws_alb_target_group.name.arn}"`

Comment: Why are you shelling out to the AWS CLI here instead of using Terraform to create the ALB listener rule?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed this by ensuring the region was correct. The default region was different from my cluster, and caused it to throw this (misleading) ARN error.

`aws configure --region CORRECT_REGION`

Answer (score 1):

You can override default region using `--region` command line parameter or environment variable `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`.

E.g.

```
aws elbv2 create-rule --region us-east-1  --listener-arn ...
```

It's especially useful if you need to run AWS CLI commands against different regions from one client machine.

Please find more details here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration-region